# Simplify the JavaScript code using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering if there is way to simplify the following code:

```
this._session = AmberFile.session;
this._sessionPath = AmberFile.sessionPath;
this._sessionDevice = AmberFile.sessionDevice;
this._ssconfig = AmberFile.ssconfig;
```

My attempt using TypeScript/ES6, but it doesn't look like it has cleaner code:

```
const {session, sessionPath, sessionDevice, ssconfig) = AmberFile
this._session = session;
this._sessionPath = sessionPath;
this._sessionDevice = session;
this._ssconfig = sessionPath;

let context: any = {  
  sessionPath: this._sessionPath, 
  session: this._session,
  sessionDevice: this._sessionDevice
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is:

```
 Object.assign(this,{
         _session:AmberFile.session,
         _sessionPath:AmberFile.sessionPath
 })
```

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Read more:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Thanks. I Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
const {
    session: _session,
    sessionPath: _sessionPath,
    sessionDevice: _sessionDevice
} = AmberFile;
Object.assign(this, { _session, _sessionPath, _sessionDevice });
```

See [TS Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20AmberFile%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20session%3A%20'sessionVal'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionPath%3A%20'sessionPathVal'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionDevice%3A%20'sessionDeviceVal'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20etc%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20session%3A%20_session%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionPath%3A%20_sessionPath%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionDevice%3A%20_sessionDevice%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20AmberFile%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.assign(this%2C%20%7B%20_session%2C%20_sessionPath%2C%20_sessionDevice%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(this._session)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(this._sessionPath)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(this._sessionDevice)%3B)